# PHP assigning variables from a text file

Tags: php, while-loop

```
$fp = fopen ("branches.txt", "r");
while ($branch = fgets ($fp)) {
    $branch=trim($branch);
    if (filesize('branches.txt') == 0){
       echo "The file is DEFINITELY empty";
    }
    printf("%2d: ");
    if ($branch === FALSE) print ("FALSE\n");
    else print ($branch . "</br>");
}
while ($info = fscanf($fp, "%i %lf %lf")) {
   list ($properties, $income, $expenditure) = $info;
   echo $info;
}
fclose ($fp);
```

Text Editer: Location/String Integer Float Float

i.e isver heat 12 160.0 77.0

Above I have a code snippet where I am trying to read variables from a tet file. I am new to PHP and I cant see where I am going wrong because it is outputting ArrayArray, whereas I need to output the data from the text file as variables. Can anybody help me as to where I am going wrong?

Comment: `echo $properties, $income, $expenditure;`

Comment: @u_mulder I tested that already but it outputs one set of values from the text editor, not all of them?

Comment: On every iteration you will see values from current line.

Comment: @u_mulder does that mean adding an increment? and apart from that, does the code look good and correct?

Answer (score 0):

Theres no reason for you to invent your own fileformat to store variables. For example you can save your variables in an array and use serialize and unserialize to read them:

```
  <?php 
// assign html setting form to variable 
$name=$_REQUEST['name'];
$age=$_REQUEST['age']; 
    // set and write data for example
    $store = array(
                'name' => $name,
                'age' =>$age,

            );

    $fp = fopen('info.txt','w');

    fwrite($fp,serialize($store));


    // Reading the data
    $infotxt = file_get_contents('info.txt');
    $info = unserialize($infotxt);


    // Now you can access those normally like arrays:
    echo $info['name'];
    echo $info['age'];

    // Or if you want those to be variables you can use extract function
    extract($info);

    echo $name;
    echo $age;
    ?>
```